# How to prove the function $f$ has an antiderivative?

Tags: real-analysis

There is a question in our analysis book and I have lots of problem with it. It says that:

set

$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
 0 \quad & x\leq0\\
 \sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) \quad & x>0
 \end{cases}
$$

$$
g(x)=
 \begin{cases}
 0 \quad & x\leq0\\
 1 \quad & x>0.
 \end{cases}
$$

prove that $f$ has an antiderivative but $g$ does not.

My first problem is about antiderivative of $g$. I think it has an antiderivative and it is

\begin{align*}
G(x)=&\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
 0 \quad & x\leq0\\
 x \quad & x>0.
 \end{array}
\right.
\end{align*}

Why we can't say that $G$ is antiderivative of $g$? My second problem is about finding the antiderivative of $f$. As you may know antiderivative of $\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$ can not be shown by the elementary functions. So, to prove that $f$ has antiderivative I can't find a function like $F$ which its derivative is $f$ and I need to use another approach to prove it, but I don't have any idea about what should I do?

Comment: What is $G'(0)$ ?

Comment: $G$ isn't differentiable at $0$. For $f$, the thing to show is that $$\lim_{x\downarrow 0} \frac{1}{x}\int_0^x \sin \frac{\pi}{t}\,dt = 0.$$

Comment: Your guess for the possible antiderivative of $g$ is correct. You have to show however that this is the only possibility. Once that is done, show that $G$ in fact does not have a derivative at $x = 0$. Therefore, $g$ in fact does not have an antiderivative.

Comment: For the first, let $h(x)=\cases{x^2\cos(\pi/x), &$x>0$\cr 0, &$x\le0$}$ and $q(x)= \cases{    2x\cos(\pi/x), &$x>0$ \cr 0, &$x\le 0$ }$. Then $q$ is a derivative (as all continuous functions are), $h$ is differentiable, and $f= (h'-q)/\pi$.

Comment: This post is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1815653/does-such-kind-of-function-exsists

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$G(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xg(t)\,dt.$$

For $x\ne0$, $G'(x)=g(x)$, but $G'(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x)$, use the Taylor expansion of sine about zero to express $$\sin \left( \frac{\pi}{x} \right)$$ as an infinite sum. From there, integrate across the sum to give a function for the antiderivative.

As for your expression for $G$, the problem is that $g$ is not defined at zero. Given that an antiderivative, by definition, has a derivative, we can say that $g$ has no antiderivative.