# Does such kind of function exsists?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Consider the signum function denoted by $f$. Does there exist a function $g$ such that $g′(x) = f(x)$ ?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Comment: This post is - to some extent - related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1302879/how-to-prove-the-function-f-has-an-antiderivative

Answer (score 3):

No, because derivatives have the intermediate value property: if $f$ is the derivative of $g$ and is $f(x)$ is defined for every $x$ in an interval $[a, b]$, then for every $y$ between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, there's a value $c \in [a, b]$ with $f(c) = y$.

In your case, pick $a = -1, b = 1$, so that $f(a) = -1$ and $f(b) = 1$ and then pick $y = 0.3$, for instance.

(This fact about derivatives is known as ["Darboux's theorem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), by the way.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a function $g(x)$ with the complete real line as its domain, then @John Hughes answer already said everything. Howsoever, if you're fine with restricting the domain of $g(x)$ by defining it on $\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$, then you can work with
$$
g(x)=\lvert x \rvert\;,x\in\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}
$$
which will give you
$$
g'(x)=\mathrm{sign}(x) 
$$
Again, if you consider $g(x)$ on the complete real line, it won't be differentiable in $0$.